# How to forbid create process on Android?

Tags: android

Serveral application in my Nexus5X can't be killed.(even `#kill -9`)It always restart by itself:(

Is there any way to forbid them being created?

How to implement programmatically?

Comment: stackoverflow.com is for programming questions.  This sounds like a more general Android question, which you'll have better luck with on http://android.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Settings > Apps > (Click on App) > Uninstall/Disable?